Spritekit crashes sporadically on SKAction.move
I'm developing an app that moves a "grid" with Spritekit SKAction.move, based on frequent updates from ARKit. It crashes sporadically at camera?.run(moveToAction). Sometimes the app runs for 10-15 mins without problem so it's hard to debug. I'm fairly inexperienced and any help is highly appreciated.
    func setupScene(scale: String, root: String) {
        removeAllChildren()
        cameraNode.removeAllChildren()
        if (scale == "Free Pitch") {
            spritesheetNode = SKSpriteNode(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "grid6"))
        } else if (scale == "Chromatic") {
            spritesheetNode = SKSpriteNode(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "chromatic"))
        } else  {
            if (scale == "Minor Pentatonic" || scale == "Major Pentatonic") {
                spritesheetNode = SKSpriteNode(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "pentatonic7"))
            } else if (scale == "Minor" || scale == "Major") {
                spritesheetNode = SKSpriteNode(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "diatonic"))
            } else if (scale == "Harmonic Minor") {
                spritesheetNode = SKSpriteNode(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "diatonic"))
            } else if (scale == "Whole Tone"){
                spritesheetNode = SKSpriteNode(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "wholenote"))
            } else if (scale == "Diminished"){
                spritesheetNode = SKSpriteNode(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "dimarp"))
            } else if (scale == "Major3rd"){
                spritesheetNode = SKSpriteNode(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "major3rdarp"))
            } else if (scale == "Quarter"){
                spritesheetNode = SKSpriteNode(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "quartal"))
            }
            getScale(scale: scale, root: root)
        }
        let heightFactor = 0.2667
        let width = 2000.0
       
        spritesheetNode.size = CGSize(width: width, height: heightFactor * width)
        spritesheetNode.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x:0.179, y:0.3)
        yPosition = size.height/2
        spritesheetNode.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: yPosition)
        
        backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        addChild(spritesheetNode)
        camera = cameraNode
        addChild(cameraNode)
        cameraNode.position = spritesheetNode.position
        staticObjectsNode.size = CGSize(width: 600, height: 140)
        staticObjectsNode.position = CGPoint(x:0.5, y:340)
        staticObjectsNode.zPosition = 1
        cameraNode.addChild(staticObjectsNode)
    }

    func animateCamera(xMovement: Float) {
        let sensitivity: Float = appState.conductor.currentSynth.sensitivity
        var x = xMovement
        if (appState.selectedScaleOption == "Free Pitch" || appState.selectedScaleOption == "Chromatic") {
            let increment: Float = 0.1412;
            x = xMovement * sensitivity / 85.0 + (((-xMovement * sensitivity / 85.0 / 0.14 - 0.071425).rounded(.down) + 1.0) * increment)
        } else if (appState.selectedScaleOption == "Minor Pentatonic" || appState.selectedScaleOption == "Major Pentatonic") {
            let increment: Float = 0.0588;
            x = xMovement * sensitivity / 85.0 + (((-xMovement * sensitivity / 85.0 / increment + 0.03).rounded(.down) + 1.0) * increment)
        } else if (appState.selectedScaleOption == "Minor" || appState.selectedScaleOption == "Major" || appState.selectedScaleOption == "Harmonic Minor") {
            let increment: Float = 0.08235;
            x = xMovement * sensitivity / 85.0 + (((-xMovement * sensitivity / 85.0 / increment).rounded(.down) + 1.0) * increment)
        } else if (appState.selectedScaleOption == "Whole Tone") {
            let increment: Float = 0.0706;
            x = xMovement * sensitivity / 85.0 + (((-xMovement * sensitivity / 85.0 / increment).rounded(.down) + 1.0) * increment)
        } else if (appState.selectedScaleOption == "Diminished") {
            let increment: Float = 0.04705;
            x = xMovement * sensitivity / 85.0 + (((-xMovement * sensitivity / 85.0 / increment).rounded(.down) + 1.0) * increment)
        } else if (appState.selectedScaleOption == "Major3rd") {
            let increment: Float = 0.03523;
            x = xMovement * sensitivity / 85.0 + (((-xMovement * sensitivity / 85.0 / increment).rounded(.down) + 1.0) * increment)
        } else if (appState.selectedScaleOption == "Quarter") {
            let increment: Float = 0.1412;
            x = xMovement * sensitivity / 85.0 + (((-xMovement * sensitivity / 85.0 / increment).rounded(.down) + 1.0) * increment)
        }
        
        let xPosition: Double = Double(x * 19300 * 0.375)
        let point = CGPoint(x: xPosition, y: yPosition)
        let moveToAction = SKAction.move(to: point, duration: 0.005)
        
        camera?.run(moveToAction)
    }

Exception   NSException *   "*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds for empty array"

sensitivity:    Float   85
x:  Float   0.122448787
xPosition:  Double  886.2230224609375
point:  CGPoint (x = 886.2230224609375, y = 422)    
moveToAction:   SKMove  0x0000000303389c40  

    0x1f5c9cf6c <+364>: ldrsw  x8, [x19, #0xac]
    0x1f5c9cf70 <+368>: stp    x20, x21, [sp, #-0x10]!
    0x1f5c9cf74 <+372>: adrp   x20, 11
    0x1f5c9cf78 <+376>: add    x20, x20, #0x332          ; "BUG IN LIBPTHREAD: __workq_kernreturn returned"
    0x1f5c9cf7c <+380>: adrp   x21, 21192
    0x1f5c9cf80 <+384>: add    x21, x21, #0x8            ; gCRAnnotations
    0x1f5c9cf84 <+388>: str    x20, [x21, #0x8]
    0x1f5c9cf88 <+392>: str    x8, [x21, #0x38]
    0x1f5c9cf8c <+396>: ldp    x20, x21, [sp], #0x10
    0x1f5c9cf90 <+400>: ldp    x29, x30, [sp, #0x20]
    0x1f5c9cf94 <+404>: ldp    x20, x19, [sp, #0x10]
    0x1f5c9cf98 <+408>: ldp    x22, x21, [sp], #0x30
    0x1f5c9cf9c <+412>: retab  
    0x1f5c9cfa0 <+416>: mov    x0, x19
    0x1f5c9cfa4 <+420>: bl     0x1f5ca1814               ; _pthread_wqthread_exit
    0x1f5c9cfa8 <+424>: bl     0x1f5ca1854               ; _pthread_wqthread_legacy_worker_wrap
    0x1f5c9cfac <+428>: b      0x1f5c9cee4               ; <+228>
    0x1f5c9cfb0 <+432>: mov    x0, x22
    0x1f5c9cfb4 <+436>: bl     0x1f5ca6680               ; _pthread_wqthread.cold.1

Stacktrace:
* thread #49, queue = 'com.apple.scenekit.renderingQueue.ARSCNView0x101e40b10', stop reason = hit Objective-C exception
    frame #0: 0x000000019d0a2f3c libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_throw
    frame #1: 0x00000001a5172b7c CoreFoundation`-[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:] + 1688
    frame #2: 0x00000001fea84210 SpriteKit`-[SKNode _runAction:] + 96
    frame #3: 0x00000001fea84168 SpriteKit`-[SKNode runAction:] + 56
  * frame #4: 0x00000001005fd784 Etherizer`NoteScene.animateCamera(xMovement=0.0138236824, self=0x0000000101e54a60) at NoteScene.swift:245:17
    frame #5: 0x00000001006603f8 Etherizer`ARViewController.renderer(renderer=__C.SCNSceneRenderer @ 0x000000016f9d6428, time=7930.3236692083346, self=0x0000000101d35eb0) at ContentView.swift:363:25
    frame #6: 0x00000001006606cc Etherizer`@objc ARViewController.renderer(_:updateAtTime:) at <compiler-generated>:0
    frame #7: 0x00000001ff037120 SceneKit`-[SCNRenderer _update:] + 360
    frame #8: 0x00000001ff0393c4 SceneKit`-[SCNRenderer _drawSceneWithNewRenderer:] + 156
    frame #9: 0x00000001ff0398dc SceneKit`-[SCNRenderer _drawScene:] + 44
    frame #10: 0x00000001ff039c00 SceneKit`-[SCNRenderer _drawAtTime:] + 504
    frame #11: 0x00000001ff0dba14 SceneKit`-[SCNView _drawAtTime:] + 372
    frame #12: 0x00000001fef85248 SceneKit`__83-[NSObject(SCN_DisplayLinkExtensions) SCN_setupDisplayLinkWithQueue:screen:policy:]_block_invoke + 48
    frame #13: 0x00000001ff0a170c SceneKit`-[SCNDisplayLink _displayLinkCallbackReturningImmediately] + 140
    frame #14: 0x0000000101bba7bc libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 20
    frame #15: 0x0000000101bbd8e0 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_continuation_pop + 676
    frame #16: 0x0000000101bd4cc8 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_source_latch_and_call + 480
    frame #17: 0x0000000101bd3718 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_source_invoke + 860
    frame #18: 0x0000000101bc24a4 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 376
    frame #19: 0x0000000101bc3408 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_lane_invoke + 408
    frame #20: 0x0000000101bd0404 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_wlh + 328
    frame #21: 0x0000000101bcfa38 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 444
    frame #22: 0x0000000201124f20 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_wqthread + 288


The "point" seems to be as it should, I'm having trouble debugging this since it happens sporadically and might be at lower level. It might be better to not use move action when it is this frequent, but i find it smoother than updating the position directly.

Can you provide the stacktrace?

trying to get it to crash again :) How do I get the kind of more verbose stack trace?

Typing thread backtrace in the Xcode console should do it.

Alright thanks a lot, I haven't been able to reproduce it all day, but will get back to you with the stacktrace once it shows up again.

Updated with stacktrace now. The error has not showed up for  a while but now it did once again. Could this be related ro hardware since other apps crash on my phone sometimes?

OK so NoteScene.swift:245:17 is where you need to focus.  It looks like an issue with an array within an SKNode, no doubt an out-of-bounds.  If there is multi-threading is play here, then I would look thread sync issues.  Other than that I don't really know.
